# Using a SumProduct Function replace blanks or zeros with 1's

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a very complicated sumproduct function that I need to add on a block for quantities. The catch is that I need it to treat blanks or zeros as ones. Example data as shown below.

| Value | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 5 |  |
| 6 | 2 |
| 8 | 4 |
| 4 |  |
| 2 | 6 |

Something like Sumproduct(A2:A6,Max(B2:B6,1)), though this doesn't work.

This should come out to 65 if I did my math right.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A6*((B2:B6=0)+B2:B6))
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A6*TEXT(B2:B6,"0;-0;1;"))
```

Comment: FWIW, OP says - I need it to treat blanks **or zeros** as ones_ The first formula does not handle `0`'s (changing it to `=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A6*((B2:B6=0)+B2:B6))` fixes that).  Second formula does not handle -ve quantities.  If that's a requirement, change the format string to `"0;-0,1;"`